# Saving RTSP stream with VLC

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, rtsp, vlc

I'm trying to save 5 seconds .mov segments of an RTSP stream with VLC. First I tried openRTSP and ffmpeg but both of them gives incorrect output (Index missing etc). I've read a lot of the VLC cli, but havn't had any luck of saving an RTSP stream as segments.

If I use the VLC GUI I can both save segments as saving snapshots (PNGs) but I need to do this via CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mov files are not streamable. [they are right in saying index file missing]. I don't even know how you are sending them over rtsp there is no rtp payloader i am aware of for mov/mp4 format.